# Chrome mouse wheel scroll causes rendering error. Is it only me?

Tags: google-chrome

I having rendering issues when I use my mouse wheel when scrolling, if I use scroll bar it's OK. Has anyone come across this problem? It feels annoying. I will post a solution here if I can find what’s the problem. My chrome version at the moment is: **21.0.1180.83 m**

**See screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I've not seen anything like that. (21.0.1180.83 m on Windows 7)

Comment: @AlEverett Are you on x64? (then I am wondering if this has anything to do with my graphics card driver)